# How to calculate distance in a 2ndArray?

Tags: java, algorithm, opencv

For some picture analysis, I am searching for an efficient algorithm to calculate the distance from some (x,y)-Point to another point in a Array which have the same values.

I want to use it to detect large areas that contains the same color. Does someone have an idea?

For example I have the following matrix and want detect the left square on top.

```
  [0 255 255 0 0  ]
  [0 255 255 0 0  ]
  [0 255 0   0 0  ]
  [0 0   0   0 255]
```

Comment: What constitutes "large areas"? Some input with expected output would be great.

Comment: an example: i wrote a color detector, which create a new image (a mask ) of the detected color:
Orginal:http://www.pic-upload.de/view-14840565/blueSky1.jpg" 
Detected blue:http://www.pic-upload.de/view-14840555/colorDetectorTest__blueSky1.jpg.jpg
Now i want get some informations about the location of the white pixels

Answer (score 1):

You could consider matrix as a graph. Consider each cell as a node. If two neighboring cells have the same value, then assume that there is a connection between these cells. find all the connected components in the graph and then find out the largest connected component.

Another very related method is [Region Growing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing) algorithm. The idea is to use recursion to visit all the near-by nodes from a given seed pixel. So, in your case, if you can supply one seed point with the given color, the algorithm would be able to find all the region built up from the given point. This could be a starting point and you could try searching for finding the largest area using region growing as a base-approach.